# Как записать данные из формы в базу данных mysql? PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Сколько уже не перепробовал с разных сайтов, не хочет записывать в мою БД(((
Помогите плиз, данные от БД такие
Хост: localhost
Пользователь: 1
Пароль: 1
Имя БД: vk2
Имя таблицы: users
Нужно занести в бд: id, login, password

Comment: Не нужно минусовать и репортить такие вопросы. Стаковерфлой задумывался для ответов именно на такие вопросы, а не "памагитя ничево ниработит". Закрывать вопрос "как сделать то-то" следует только если есть дубликат с нормальным ответом

Answer (score 3):

Дополню ответ колеги для случая, когда данные для запроса берутся из переменных

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();

$id = $mysqli->isert_id;
```

Что здесь происходит?

1. Код соединения не стоит писать в каждом скрипте, его лучше положить в отдельный файл и инклюдить. По минимуму, код в этом файле должен быть такой

   ```
    <?php
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', '1', '1', 'vk2');
    $db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
   ```
2. Получаем переменные `$email` и `$password` для вставки
3. Создаем запрос, в котором на месте реальных данных стоят знаки вопроса
4. Подготавливаем его
5. Привязываем к нему переменные функцией bind_param, где первым параметром идёт строка из букв "s", в которой количество букв равно количеству переменных, а дальше - сами переменные
6. Выполняем
7. Получаем id

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', '1', '1', 'vk2');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$mysqli->query("
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");

$mysqli->query("
INSERT INTO test VALUES(
NULL,
'test'
)
");
```