# PHP не могу подключится к базе данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Я пытаюсь подключиться и передать данные в MySQL но к сожалению у мня ничего не выходит.

vardump($dbh)- На странице выдает:

```
mysqli::__set_state(array(
   'affected_rows' => NULL,
   'client_info' => NULL,
   'client_version' => NULL,
   'connect_errno' => NULL,
   'connect_error' => NULL,
   'errno' => NULL,
   'error' => NULL,
   'error_list' => NULL,
   'field_count' => NULL,
   'host_info' => NULL,
   'info' => NULL,
   'insert_id' => NULL,
   'server_info' => NULL,
   'server_version' => NULL,
   'stat' => NULL,
   'sqlstate' => NULL,
   'protocol_version' => NULL,
   'thread_id' => NULL,
   'warning_count' => NULL,
))
```

Сам код:

```
<?php

function uploadCSV($file){
    
    $filename = uniqid().".csv";
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], "uploads/". $filename);
    return $filename;
}


function vardump($var) {
    highlight_string(var_export($var, true) );
  }
$dbh =new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "", "api_db"); 
if ($dbh->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$filename = uploadCSV($_FILES["userfile"]);
$file_array = file('./uploads/' . $filename);
array_shift($file_array);
foreach($file_array as $value){
    $arr = explode(",", $value);
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`UID`, `Name`, `Age`, `Email`, `Phone`, `Gender`) VALUES ($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2], $arr[3], $arr[4], $arr[5])";
    $dbh->query($sql);
}
vardump($dbh);
```

Comment: запрос у тебя кстати все равно не будет работать, потому что кривой

Comment: А сама база данных то установлена корректно? Сервис работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо выкинуть весь этот пещерный карго культ из прошлого века со всеми этими "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL :(", а [соединяться нормально](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); // сообщать об ошибках
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port); // соединиться
$mysqli->set_charset($charset); // выставить кодировку
```

но главное **не путаться потом**, в какой переменной у тебя лежит соединение.

Comment: Очень странно, в итоге получил ошибку где указано что запрашивается не корректный синтаксис. Копия ошибки: "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@textmail.com, 01243453425, male )' at line 1 in C:\Fork\PHPs\uppload.php:37 Stack trace: #0 C:\Fork\PHPs\uppload.php(37): mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `ta...')"

Comment: Естественно, про кавычки-то ты не знаешь, а mysql не обязан догадываться.

Comment: ну разумеется получил, оно для того и предназначено. я писал тебе выше, что запрос не будет работать вот мой ответ где написно как **правильно** [выполнять запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1145125/179379)

Comment: @u_mulder ЗАБУДЬ слово кавычки, они тут вообще не при чем

Comment: Он был скопирован с PHPmyAdmin, указал лишь собственные данные получаемые с массива.. Где не указаны кавычки?

Comment: Не надо ничего копировать, надо делать так как у меня по ссылке написано

Comment: Мне нужен SQL запрос. Изменил подключение как указано по ссылке. Спасибо огромное зза помощь, но запрос все равно не корректный(

Comment: О господи.  @Locker **просто делай как тебе говорят**

Comment: @Ипатьев Да он сделал, просто ему теперь ссылка на подготовленные выражения нужна.

Comment: Такая вот https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/insert

Comment: там не по-русски

Comment: Все еще падает ошибка( Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in. Количество столбцов соответствует количеству передаваемых переменных. Но Так и нет результата. Всего 6 значений. Вводимый код:    ` 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO person (UID,Name,Age,Email,Phone,Gender) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $stmt= $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("issssss", $arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2], $arr[3], $arr[4], $arr[5]);
    $stmt->execute();`

Comment: @Locker значит надо посмотреть на запрос и разобраться, какого значения не хватает.

Comment: Есть возможность связаться?

Comment: @Locker ну у тебя же **шесть** полей, а ты добавляешь только три значения

Comment: Вижу) Спасибо...

Comment: Не нужна тут никакая связь, просто поставь 6 знаков вопроса, а не 3

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109884/discussion-between-locker-and-).