# PHPstorm подчеркивает переменную, как не определенную, хотя она была определена в подключаемом через include файле

Tags: php, include

есть файл connect.php, который содержит подключение к бд

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd");

if($connect == false) {
    echo 'Не подключился!';
    exit();
}
```

хотел просто подключать его к другим файлам посредством include или require, но когда обращаюсь к переменной $connect из других файлов, предварительно подключив при помощи include, интерпретатор говорит, что переменной не существует. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: надо смотреть как обращаешься, и как подключаешь

Comment: скорее всего потому что обращение происходит внутри функции. Но для того чтобы получить подробный ответ, надо сначала задать подробный вопрос. И не на словах объяснять что там к чему подключается и кем вызывается, а **все это должно быть описано в виде кода**.

Comment: И кстати, это ужасный код для поключения. Вот тут написано, [как подключаться правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1146044/179379)

Comment: И чтобы не было вопросов - при include код просто целиком включается в вызывающий файл, то есть передавать ничего никуда не надо. все уже и так есть и доступно

Comment: @Ипатьев  большое спасибо. Все по факту подключалось и нормально работает, только phpstorm подсвечивает, как неопределенную переменную. Подскажите, почему этот метод подключения плох и в чем различия?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. 1. echo 'Не подключился!'; - это глупость. Пользователю сайта эта фраза вообще не нужна, а программисту вместо неё нужно **подробное описание ошибки**, чтобы её исправить. 2. условие if($connect == false) { не нужно, потому что mysqli умеет сообщать об ошибках самостоятельно, надо только включить соответствующую настройку. 3. И вот эту настройку надо включить обязательно, чтобы не писать под каждым запросом такое вот "Не подключилсо" 4. Надо обязательно указывать при соединении кодировку, чтобы потом не писать в очередной раз на ruSO "у меня на месте русских букв кракозябры!"

Comment: А по поводу проблемы со штормом, вот ссылка на несколько решений, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22476778/285587. И на будущее, в вопросе всегда надо описывать ровно ту проблему, с столкнулись, а не свои догадки о её причинах.